# Is the dynamic library the same memory location in different processes?

Tags: c, dll, process, shared-libraries

I want to know how the dynamic library is used in different processes. Will they be in the same location in memory? When two processes call the same function in a dynamic library, are they using code from the same memory location?

For example, process A uses the dynamic library libA.so, and calls a function in the library, and the corresponding code will be loaded into the cache. So when process B is using this function, is it loaded into the cache by process A?

If process A executes the `printf` function on core 0, then the instructions of `glibc` will be brought from the main memory to the cache. When another process calls the `printf` function on core 1, is it using the glibc instruction in the cache (if it has not been replaced)?
If instructions from the cache are used, the time to call the function is reduced (accessing the cache is shorter than accessing the main memory). Then process B can measure the time by calling the printf function to infer whether other processes have executed the printf function? (Consider the ideal situation)

Is there only one copy of the instructions of the dynamic library in the cache?

Could someone please give an example with the most commonly used c dynamic library? For example `printf` function.

Really Really thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read-only segments of a dynamic library (code and constant data) are shared by all processes which load this library. In each process the virtual address of the library will be different due to security reasons (see [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) for more details) but there will be only one copy of library in real physical memory.

Code and data are stored in caches based on their physical addresses (not virtual addresses) which will be the same for all processes. So in your example processes A and B will share the libA.so's code in cache.